# Crossfading Images in SwiftUI doesn't seem to work

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, xcode11

I'd like to achieve an an animated background that crossfades a bunch of images in SwiftUI.

I've managed to get an array of Colors to crossfade nicely between them using the following code snippets, but if I replace the array of Colors with an array of Images the same approach doesn't work. The images are replaced, but not animated. Yet both a Color and an Image are of type some View right?

The following works:

```
struct ImageBackgroundView: View {

  @State private var index = 0

  private let colors:[Color] = [.red, .blue, .green, .orange, .pink, .black]
  private let timer = Timer.publish(every: 5, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()

  var body: some View {
    colors[self.index]
      .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 1))
      .onReceive(timer) { _ in
        print(self.index)
        self.index += 1
        if self.index > 5 { self.index = 0 }
      }
  }
```

but, if I replace the [Color] array with an array of type [Images], as follows, the images are transitioned, but the crossfade doesn't appear to work:

```
struct ImageBackgroundView: View {

  @State private var index = 0

  private let images = (1...8).map { Image("background\($0)") }
  private let timer = Timer.publish(every: 5, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()

  var body: some View {
    images[self.index]
      .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 1))
      .onReceive(timer) { _ in
        print(self.index)
        self.index += 1
        if self.index > 5 { self.index = 0 }
      }
  }
```

Can anyone shed any light on why this might be the case? Is it just a bug in SwiftUI at the present time?

I achieved a similar effect in a previous app using all sorts of addSubview calls animating the opacity of overlaying views - all sorts of stuff we shouldn't need to fiddle with in this brave new SwiftUI world right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I changed your example a little and now background images changed with animation. But I can't suggest, why the same things don't work either for `Color` or for `Image`. So, here is my working example, maybe it will push you in right direction:

```swift
struct AnimatedBackground: View {

    @State private var index = 0

    private let images: [Image] = ["trash", "star", "circle", "circle.fill", "square", "cloud"].map{ Image(systemName: $0) }
    private let timer = Timer.publish(every: 3, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {

            ForEach(images.indices, id: \.self) { imageIndex in
                self.images[imageIndex]
                    .resizable()
                    .transition(.opacity)
                    .opacity(imageIndex == self.index ? 1 : 0)
            }

        }
        .onReceive(timer) { _ in
            withAnimation {
                self.index = self.index < self.images.count - 1 ? self.index + 1 : 0
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: This one is really crossfade.

Comment: This solution works perfectly and delivers a really nice crossfade, if slowed down. The only amendment I made to it was to set the timer back to firing every couple of minutes and change the withAnimation { to withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 10)) {

Answer (score 4):

This is interesting and it got me thinking.

You can use a flag, say `show`. And a `ZStack` that holds your `image` object.
And then use `transition` combined with `animation` you want in that `image`.

But, only do that if `show` is `true`.

Attach the `.onReceive` event to the `ZStack` instead of your `image`. In that event, toggle the flag `show`.

```
@State private var index = 0
@State private var show = true

private let images = (1...8).map { Image("background\($0)") }
private let timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()

var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        if self.show {
            images[self.index]
                .transition(AnyTransition.opacity.animation(.easeInOut(duration: 1.0)))
        }
    }.onReceive(timer) { _ in
        print(self.index)
        self.index += 1
        self.show.toggle()
        if self.index > 4 { self.index = 0 }

    }
}
```

Voila!

[image]

---

Also, as far as I know, `Color` is not a `View`.

> A Color is a late-binding token: SwiftUI only resolves it to a
>   concrete value just before using it in a given environment.

ref: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/color

Comment: interesting, in your variant only one image is present in ```ZStack```, I did it in other way (holding all the images, but showing only one). Just curious, do our solutions have difference in memory management/etc.? But your mention about ```Color``` should be helpful, it deserves upvote just like cute dogs pictures xD

Comment: I actually compared your solution to mine. They both consume same memory. As for the performance, I doubt there's a significant difference too, unless we're talking huge amount of data? It's just multiple views anyways.

Comment: It is not crossfade, just fade-in/fade-out... and Color is a View in SwiftUI, just in case.

Comment: Yes, this does what it says on the tin, but you need quite a quick animation otherwise the screen is left blank. Not quite the effect I'm aiming for - a definite fade in/out whereas I'm looking for a smoother crossfade, but thanks anyway.